# Django - Hod do I request cURL from views

Tags: django, curl, django-views

I am beginner to Django. I have cURL code, I want to run it from django views and get response.

cURL code:

curl -X POST \

```
  -u "rzp_test_yourTestApiKey:yourTestApiSecret" \
  --data "period=monthly" \
  --data "interval=2" \
  --data "item[name]=Test plan" \
  --data "item[amount]=50000" \
  --data "item[currency]=INR" \
  https://api.razorpay.com/v1/plans
```

Could someone please help me with this? or let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the python `requests` library.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/plans"
data = {'period': 'monthly', 'interval': '2', 'item[name]': 'test plan', 'item[amount]': '50000', 'item[currency]': 'INR'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, auth=('rzp_test_yourTestApiKey', 'yourTestApiSecret'))
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your response. I asked other question at a different post, I didn't get any answer for that. I am wondering if you might know answer for that. Here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846973/django-return-the-response-to-view-function Thanks for the help.